# postgresql log queries single database

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL (8.3) with multiple databases... I'm wondering if there is some way to log the queries made *only* in one of the databases (not all of them).

Or to have one logfile per database...

I know I can use `log_line_prefix = "%d"` to log the name of the database, and then filter, but that is not the issue.

Should I maybe use a log_analyzer to get around this ? Do you have any recommendations ?

thanks

Comment: should I post this elsewhere ? where ?

Comment: If you're not satisfied with any of the answers you've gotten here let me know and I can move it to our DBA site ([dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)).  Frank's answer seems to be exactly what you're looking for though.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, you can set the configuration parameter [`log_statement`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT) per database:

```
ALTER DATABASE your_database_name
SET log_statement = 'all';
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit I've never seen this before -- has it been around a while?

Comment: I really didn't try out this answer, since I don't need it right away anymore. But if it works its the best thing to do ! : ) I'll update accordingly on the right moment

Comment: so is @voretaq7 answer plainly wrong? please let us know!

Comment: Yes he was wrong, check the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN This setting can be changed by the superuser at any time for any database.

Comment: @Stefano Yup, I'm wrong (or at least in the case of using a view/log trigger **extremely** sub-optimal) - I haven't tried this myself though so I'm not sure if it puts the DB name into the log line or not - that's only a concern if you're enabling it for multiple DBs though and still involves less post-processing than logging *every* DB in a busy cluster.

Comment: thanks @voretaq7 and frank for the clarification! It might be useful to update that answer then to avoid readers' errors and possibly downvotes (though that wouldn't touch your reputation :) )

Comment: @Stefano I don't mind if that answer accumulates downvotes - it's a solution, but certainly not the best one.  I'd much rather see Frank's solution upvoted more though - it should really be outscoring my answer by a lot more than one vote!

Comment: Is there any necessary options on `postgresql.conf` for this to work?

Comment: make sure to set `log_statement = 'none';`  in `postgresql.conf` otherwise you will still see all databases in your logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're logging statements via Postgres there's no way to do this per-database that I'm aware of (short of writing a view that calls a logging trigger for **every table** -- obviously not realistic).

The best available solution is what you've described (prefix each line with the database name) and feed the data to something like [`syslog-ng`](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng) to split the query log up per database.

Post-processing the log file is also an option, but be aware of potential problems (OS/filesystem max file size limits, disk space exhaustion) for database clusters that have large numbers of queries.
Also note that you do pay a performance penalty for logging all queries - how big a penalty depends on how big the queries are...