# Is it possible to set up individual logging files for specific database in Postgresql?

Tags: logging, postgresql

**Update**
What I mean is can I have multiple log files per database?  Probably not but I was curious if there was anything possible like this out of the box with Postgresql or if you required a third party product or building your own app to do this.

I saw from another [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/376699/postgresql-log-queries-single-database/376888#376888?newreg=cde4e3f4cd7f4508a02359cd8fde100b) you can do this:

*ALTER DATABASE your_database_name
SET log_statement = 'all';*

I was looking through the online documentation and I found this link for [logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/runtime-config-logging.html)

with:

log_filename (string)
When logging_collector is enabled, this parameter sets the file names of the created log files. The value is treated as a strftime pattern, so %-escapes can be used to specify time-varying file names. (Note that if there are any time-zone-dependent %-escapes, the computation is done in the zone specified by log_timezone.) The supported %-escapes are similar to those listed in the Open Group's strftime specification. Note that the system's strftime is not used directly, so platform-specific (nonstandard) extensions do not work. The default is postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log.

*If you specify a file name without escapes, you should plan to use a log rotation utility to avoid eventually filling the entire disk. In releases prior to 8.4, if no % escapes were present, PostgreSQL would append the epoch of the new log file's creation time, but this is no longer the case.
If CSV-format output is enabled in log_destination, .csv will be appended to the timestamped log file name to create the file name for CSV-format output. (If log_filename ends in .log, the suffix is replaced instead.)*

***This parameter can only be set in the postgresql.conf file or on the server command line.***

Boo, is there any way to set up logging for just a specific database on a server that anyone has ever tried?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the global `log_statement=none`. Then for the specific database:

`ALTER DATABASE my_db_name set log_statement='all'`

I also have this in my global config so the log file shows the db name and the user.
`log_line_prefix = '< %m %d %u >'`

Comment: I will give you a thumbs up because I titled my question wrong.  I meant could I have a DB1.log, DB2.log side by side.  What you are stating is exactly what I am doing as it is the best way to accomplish what I want but I was hoping I could tailor individual logs for specific databases.   Essentially though it seems that this probably is the best way to do it and then change settings later after I am done examining.